# How do I split an input String into seperate usable integers in python

Tags: python, split, coordinates, tokenize, minecraft

I'm trying to split a Input String xyz into 3 tokens and then seperating into 3 integers called x, y, and z.
I want it to do this so that I have to do less input and then be able to use them for the coordinates of `mc.setblocks(x1, y1, z1, x, y, z, BlockId)`.     How do I Separate it so that it turns out as 3 different ints and\or split them into tokens to do so? I know how I would do this in java but I have no clue of how to do it in python. It should look something like this :

```
xyz1 = input("enter first coordinates example: 102 36 74")
st = StringTokenizer(xyz1)
x = st.nextToken
y = st.nextToken
z = st.nextToken
```

Comment: Are you guaranteed they will enter 3 valid digits separated by whitespace?

Comment: I will use a exception catcher if that happens

Comment: But will they always be separated by whitespace? Cause then you can use the string.split() method.

Comment: Are those always in the form of (3 2 2) digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried writing this less "pythonically" so you can see what's happening:

```
xyz1 = input("Enter first 3 coordinates (example: 102 36 74): ")

tokens = xyz1.split() # returns a list (ArrayList) of tokenized values
try:
    x = int(tokens[0])   # sets x,y,z to the first three tokens
    y = int(tokens[1])
    z = int(tokens[2])
except IndexError:       # if 0,1,2 are out of bounds
    print("You must enter 3 values")
except ValueError:       # if the entered number was of invalid int format
    print("Invalid integer format")
```

If you have more than just three coordinates being entered, you would tokenize the input and loop over it, converting each token into an int and appending it to a list:

```
xyz1 = input("Enter first 3 coordinates (example: 102 36 74): ")

tokens = xyz1.split() # returns a list (ArrayList) of tokenized values
coords = []     # initialise empty list
for tkn in tokens:
    try:
        coords.append(int(tkn))     # convert token to int
    except ValueError:       # if the entered number was of invalid int format
        print("Invalid integer format: {}".format(tkn))
        raise
print(coords)   # coords is now a list of integers that were entered
```

Fun fact, you can do the above in a mostly one-liner. This is a more pythonic way so you can contrast this with the above to get a sense of what that means:

```
try:
    xyz1 = input("Enter first 3 coordinates (example: 102 36 74): ")
    coords = [int(tkn) for tkn in xyz1.split()]
except ValueError:       # if the entered number was of invalid int format
    print("Invalid integer format: {}".format(tkn))
    raise
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the string that is in `xyz1` and split it and turn them into integers like this

```
xyz_list = [int(x) for x in xyz1.split(' ')]
```

If you don't want these integers in a list and would prefer to store them into separate variables, just do this

```
x = xyz_list[0]
y = xyz_list[1]
z = xyz_list[2]
```

Comment: xyz1 is a string and I need to separate it and then turn the values of the separated tokens into 3 ints

Comment: Just a short side note: This generator expression is great an compact in order to solve the task. Since I think OP is in need of additional error and format handling, a more general approach using a for-loop would be more flexible.

Comment: @TheLittleCoder have you tried it? I think it will accomplish what you are asking for.

Comment: See my edit if you need the extra step of placing the elements of the list into three separate variables.

Comment: @Matt Cremeens For some weird reason it doesn't work even though I did what you said. It does this     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/arsen/Desktop/Minecraft Python/Variables/BlockStacking.py", line 7, in <module>
    xyz_1_List = ( int(coord) for coord in xyz1.split() )
NameError: name 'xyz1' is not defined

Comment: That's not my code. I think you may have got that from another answer.

Comment: Thanks You really helped me with this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split()` method of the `string` object, which defaults to splitting on whitespace characters.  This will give you a list of separate strings.  To convert each string to an `integer`, you could use a comprehension.  Assuming the input is in correct form, the following one-liner will do it:

```
x, y, z = ( int(coord) for coord in xyz1.split() )
```